# how to hide soft key in bottom sheet dialog in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I'm tryin to hide soft key on a bottom clicked in bottom sheet dialog fragment.
I already tried this :

```
    try {
        val view: View? = requireActivity().currentFocus
        if (view != null) {
            (requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager).hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                view.windowToken,
                0)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Logger.e(TAG, "can't hide the softKey --> ${e.message}", e)
    }
```

buy its not working on bottom sheet dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
    getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `requireActivity().currentFocus` isn't returning null? That seems to always happen when I try your code, and if it does it makes sense that it doesn't do anything. I'd suggest getting a view another way. As long as you're calling the function after you have returned from `onCreateView` you can just use `view` (from `getView()`):

```
val imm = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view?.windowToken, 0)
```